# 同じ処理ステップを別ルーティンとしてまとめることは可能？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

お世話になります。多くの基本的なことを理解しないで
自分のビジネスに関係したアプリをrailsで作って
いるものです。アクションのコーディング中で同じ操作
が結構あります。同じステップをいくつも記述するのはやはり
余りに見苦しいし、無駄です。それでその部分をメソッドに
するには、スコープの問題でやりにくい。あるいは
引数があまりに数が大きくなりすぎる。オブジェクト化
するほどでもないし、ちょっと大げさ過ぎます。このような
コーディングの時、簡単に同じ部分だけを別の個所に記述
して他のアクションとあるいは同じアクション内で共有する
ことはできないでしょうか？
VBAでは何か関数のオプションでできたような記憶が
ありますが、rubyでは可能ですか？よろしくお願い
します。

---

例えば次のようなステップがあるとします。

filea.field_a = ary[1]
filea.field_b = ary[2]
filea.field_c = ary[5]
filea.field_d = ary[6].to_i
          ・
          ・
          ・
          ・
          ・
          ・

このコーディングは変えたくない,
そして、数箇所繰り返して出現するとします。
当然同じものをコーディングしたくありません。
従って、どこか一か所に書いて共有して使えれば
便利ですし、コーディングミスも防げます。

---

フィールド名は違うかも知れないが内容は殆んど
同じです。renderで理解できないエラーが出たのと、
newとeditのアクションはコンピューターで判断
させた方がユーザーには親切だと思い、つまり
入力でキーが重複したときは自動的にedit画面に
導いた方がユーザは助かります。
そしてrenderを使わないで、すべてredirect_toで入力ミスを返しているので
アクション毎の入力データをすべてファイルで管理する
必要が有り、配列データで各フィールの値を持っています。
そして配列フィールドから最終的にマスターに登録します。
確かに異常なコーディングかもしれません。でもひと昔の
言語cobol等では簡単にできたものです。そして普通でした。

Comment: 可能な範囲で、具体的なコードを質問に追記してください。

Comment: 必要なのは模擬コードではなく具体的なコードです。模擬コードにするにしても、現実に即したものにしてください。何がしたいのか、何に困っているのかが伝わらないと誰も回答できないですよ

Comment: フィールド名は違うかもしれませんが現実に即しています。ほとんど同じです。renderで理由の分からないエラーが出て、すべてrediect_toで入力ミスのエラーを返そうとしたらセッション(アクション)毎の管理をすべてファイルでしなくてならなくなり、配列フィールドで各ビューの

Comment: もし可能であれば、ルーティング、モデル、コントローラーのコードを追加していただけますか？実現したいこととしては、コードの重複をなくす（Railsで言う所のDRY）ことだと思うのですが、もう少しコードを載せていただけると、みなさんが回答しやすいかと思います。

Comment: まずは「renderで理解できないエラーが出た」というのを解決すべきではないでしょうか。
「メソッドにするには、スコープの問題でやりにくい」というのはどういうことでしょうか。この例であれば、filea と ary を引数で渡すようにすればメソッド化はできると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えば以下のようなメソッドではいかがでしょうか。

```
# 定義
def  set_file_field_with_ary(file, ary)
    file.field_a = ary[1]
    file.field_b = ary[2]
    file.field_c = ary[5]
    file.field_d = ary[6].to_i
end

# 使用
set_file_field_with_ary(filea, ary)
```

---

参照渡しについての補足:

メソッドから変更対象のオブジェクト（`file`）を `return` していないのは、メソッドに渡されるのがオブジェクトの参照である事によります。
つまり、上のメソッドはオブジェクトのコピーを操作しているのではなく、元のオブジェクトその物を変更しています。
いわゆる「破壊的」メソッドです。

実行:

```
ary[1] = "あいう"
set_file_field_with_ary(filea, ary)
puts "変数 filea の 'field_a' の値: #{filea.field_a}"

ary[1] = "ABC"
set_file_field_with_ary(filea, ary)
puts "変数 filea の 'field_a' の値: #{filea.field_a}"
```

出力:

```
変数 filea の 'field_a' の値: あいう
変数 filea の 'field_a' の値: ABC
```

「Ruby 参照渡し」などのキーワードで検索すると、色々と解説があると思います。
（もちろん、戻り値として返した方が都合がいい場合もありますし、それでもまったく構いません）

Comment: そうなんですね。メソッドの引数は文字とか数値
といった値だと、勝手に決め込んでいたふしがあり
ました。fileをメソッドからreturnしてもらって
それぞれのアクションで違うところだけ値を
入れてやればよさそうです。
他の個所で記述しても現在のスコープと同じ
スコープでプログラムが流れないと出来ないと考えて
いました。頭固いですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 補足説明分かりました。ありがとうござうます。